# MySQL stops using index when SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is added

Tags: mysql, sql-calc-found-rows

I have a query which is running far slower than it should. I have distilled the problem down to a simple select statement (some fields have been renamed for privacy):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, date_started, date_complete, status
FROM table_a
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

When `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is used then query completes in about 0.70 seconds, however when `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is removed then the query completes in about 0.0005 seconds (in both cases `SQL_NO_CACHE` is used in the query).

`table_a` has an index on the `date` field.

Apparently SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS [can prevent an index from being used:](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)

> So, obvious conclusion from this simple test is: when we have
>   appropriate indexes for WHERE/ORDER clause in our query, it is much
>   faster to use two separate queries instead of one with
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

I have confirmed this. No index is used when `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is included:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, date_started, date_complete, status FROM table_a ORDER BY date DESC limit 0, 100;
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_a     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 132208 | Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
```

But when `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is not used then the index on the date field is used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, date_started, date_complete, status FROM table_a ORDER BY date DESC limit 0, 100;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_a     | index | NULL          | date | 13      | NULL | 132208 |       | 
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
```

**Is there any way to speed the query up without removing `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` from the query?**

I'm using MySQL version 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.1-log.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The percona answer you link to has an exhaustive answer.

Comment: Use separate `select count(*)` query.

Comment: the bold bit is the question. i'm basically asking if anybody knows of a workaround to alter mysql behaviour. i know i could do 2 queries, but this will be a lot of effort since a lot of queries in my code use sql_calc_found_rows, so i'm asking before i go and put a month's work in.